# Move divs around on window resize with if then

Tags: jquery, window-resize, insertafter

I am trying to move some divs around when the window gets resized, shouldn't this if then statement work:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');
}
else ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $('.div1').insertBefore('.div2');
}
});
```

Also, can I trigger this when the page is loaded using .resize OR when the page is first loaded?

Comment: Could you provide more information about the error? What displays? What doesn't work? First thing I notice is that `else` can't have a condition, so remove the `($(window).width() > 1024)` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Else statements can't have a condition attached.

```
else ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    $('.div1').insertBefore('.div2');
}
});
```

has to be

```
else {
    $('.div1').insertBefore('.div2');
}
});
```

If you wan't to call this during page load, you can put it into a function and call the function both on resize and on page load.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I don't know why I was trying to make it harder on myself haha.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
    $('.div1').insertAfter('.div2');
}
else{
    $('.div1').insertBefore('.div2');
}
});
```

you can use jquery [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)